# Embedding SVGs in inside of embedded SVG

Tags: svg

I'm fairly new to SVG and wanted to know if it's possible to have nested embeddings of SVGs. For example, I'm embedding SVG 1 into SVG 2 as follows:

```
<image href="SVG-Files/SVG1.svg"></image>
```

But, when I embed SVG 2 into SVG 3, none of the embeddings from SVG are embedded into SVG 1. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: If that's an option, you can easily nest `<svg>` tags and keep everything in just one file.